# Reading CSV files in C#

Tags: c#, open-source, csv

Does anyone know of an open-source library that allows you to parse and read `.csv` files in C#?

Comment: I found one! http://www.filehelpers.com/ :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) on CodeProject.

Comment: Yeah, that one is great, aka LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv by Sebastien Lorien

Answer (score 27):

Here, written by yours truly to use generic collections and iterator blocks.  It supports double-quote enclosed text fields (including ones that span mulitple lines) using the double-escaped convention (so `""` inside a quoted field reads as single quote character).  It does not support:

- Single-quote enclosed text
- \ -escaped quoted text
- alternate delimiters (won't yet work on pipe or tab delimited fields)
- Unquoted text fields that begin with a quote

But all of those would be easy enough to add if you need them.  I haven't benchmarked it anywhere (I'd love to see some results), but performance should be *very good* - better than anything that's `.Split()` based anyway.

**[Now on GitHub](https://github.com/jcoehoorn/EasyCSV)**

**Update**: felt like adding single-quote enclosed text support.  It's a simple change, but I typed it right into the reply window so it's untested.  Use the revision link at the bottom if you'd prefer the old (tested) code.

```
public static class CSV
{
    public static IEnumerable<IList<string>> FromFile(string fileName, bool ignoreFirstLine = false)
    {
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            foreach(IList<string> item in FromReader(rdr, ignoreFirstLine)) yield return item;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IList<string>> FromStream(Stream csv, bool ignoreFirstLine=false)
    {
        using (var rdr = new StreamReader(csv))
        {
            foreach (IList<string> item in FromReader(rdr, ignoreFirstLine)) yield return item;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IList<string>> FromReader(TextReader csv, bool ignoreFirstLine=false)
    {
        if (ignoreFirstLine) csv.ReadLine();

        IList<string> result = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder curValue = new StringBuilder();
        char c;
        c = (char)csv.Read();
        while (csv.Peek() != -1)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case ',': //empty field
                    result.Add("");
                    c = (char)csv.Read();
                    break;
                case '"': //qualified text
                case '\'':
                    char q = c;
                    c = (char)csv.Read();
                    bool inQuotes = true;
                    while (inQuotes && csv.Peek() != -1)
                    {
                        if (c == q)
                        {
                            c = (char)csv.Read();
                            if (c != q)
                                inQuotes = false;
                        }

                        if (inQuotes)
                        {
                            curValue.Append(c);
                            c = (char)csv.Read();
                        } 
                    }
                    result.Add(curValue.ToString());
                    curValue = new StringBuilder();
                    if (c == ',') c = (char)csv.Read(); // either ',', newline, or endofstream
                    break;
                case '\n': //end of the record
                case '\r':
                    //potential bug here depending on what your line breaks look like
                    if (result.Count > 0) // don't return empty records
                    {
                        yield return result;
                        result = new List<string>();
                    }
                    c = (char)csv.Read();
                    break;
                default: //normal unqualified text
                    while (c != ',' && c != '\r' && c != '\n' && csv.Peek() != -1)
                    {
                        curValue.Append(c);
                        c = (char)csv.Read();
                    }
                    result.Add(curValue.ToString());
                    curValue = new StringBuilder();
                    if (c == ',') c = (char)csv.Read(); //either ',', newline, or endofstream
                    break;
            }
            
        }
        if (curValue.Length > 0) //potential bug: I don't want to skip on a empty column in the last record if a caller really expects it to be there
            result.Add(curValue.ToString());
        if (result.Count > 0) 
            yield return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can it handle commas inside quoted string? "like,this" ... and can it handle carriage returns in quoted strings? ... those are some of the things that tend to cause trouble...

Comment: Yes, it can handle both.  That's the whole point of quoted strings.

Comment: I still like this, but if I had it to do over I'd probably inherit TextReader

Comment: I'm doing a bit of game development and probably using .CSV files in early stages. I'm interested in what you have here as well as inheriting TextReader.

Answer (score 21):

The [last time this question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458068/c-reading-csv-file-gives-not-a-valid-path), here's [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458068/c-reading-csv-file-gives-not-a-valid-path/1458296#1458296) I gave:

If you're just trying to read a CSV file with C#, the easiest thing is to use the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class.  It's actually built into the .NET Framework, instead of being a third-party extension.

Yes, it is in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`, but that doesn't mean you can't use it from C# (or any other CLR language).

Here's an example of usage, taken from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx):

```
Using MyReader As New _
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\testfile.txt")
   MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
   MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
   Dim currentRow As String()
   While Not MyReader.EndOfData
      Try
         currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
         Dim currentField As String
         For Each currentField In currentRow
            MsgBox(currentField)
         Next
      Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
      MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & _
      "is not valid and will be skipped.")
      End Try
   End While
End Using
```

Again, this example is in VB.NET, but it would be trivial to translate it to C#.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about this class but it works really well.

Comment: I've used this class several times and would recommend it. Being built into .NET means you don't have to worry about licensing/distribution issues.

Answer (score 8):

I really like the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library. It's fast, it's C# 100%, it's available for **FREE**, it's very flexible and easy to use.

Comment: The FileHelpers Wizard looks really useful at creating standard classes quickly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm implementing Daniel Pryden's answer in C#, so it is easier to cut and paste and customize. I think this is the easiest method for parsing CSV files. Just add a reference and you are basically done.

Add the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` Reference to your project

Then here is sample code in C# from Joel's answer:

```
using (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser MyReader = new           
       Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filename))
{
    MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
    MyReader.SetDelimiters(",");

    while (!MyReader.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] fields = MyReader.ReadFields();
            if (first) 
            {
                first = false;
                continue;
            }

            // This is how I treat my data, you'll need to throw this out.

            //"Type"    "Post Date" "Description"   "Amount"
            LineItem li = new LineItem();

            li.date        = DateTime.Parse(fields[1]);
            li.description = fields[2];
            li.Value       = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[3]);

            lineitems1.Add(li);
        }
        catch (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Line " + ex.Message + 
                            " is not valid and will be skipped.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides parsing/reading, some libraries do other nice things like convert the parsed data into object for you.

Here is an example of using [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (a library I maintain) to read a CSV file into objects.

```
var csv = new CsvHelper( File.OpenRead( "file.csv" ) );
var myCustomObjectList = csv.Reader.GetRecords<MyCustomObject>();
```

By default, conventions are used for matching the headers/columns with the properties. You can change the behavior by changing the settings.

```
// Using attributes:
public class MyCustomObject
{
    [CsvField( Name = "First Name" )]
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    [CsvField( Index = 0 )]
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    [CsvField( Ignore = true )]
    public string ShouldIgnore { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes you don't "own" the object you want to populate the data with. In this case you can use fluent class mapping.

```
// Fluent class mapping:
public sealed class MyCustomObjectMap : CsvClassMap<MyCustomObject>
{
    public MyCustomObjectMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.StringProperty ).Name( "First Name" );
        Map( m => m.IntProperty ).Index( 0 );
        Map( m => m.ShouldIgnore ).Ignore();
    }
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand from the documentation is, when do I use mapping and when should I not use mapping? Let's say, I just want to parse an xml file and extra keywords and their attached data. Do I need to use a map for that?

Comment: If you are parsing XML, you shouldn't use a CSV library to do it. Attribute mapping no longer exists since 2.0. The reason you'd use a mapping file is if you want to change any of the default ways the library read the file. A mapping will give you a lot of control over how the file is read/written.

Comment: Opps, that was slip of tongue... I meant *CSV of course. Mapping doesn't exist in .NET 4.0/5? Also, on that note, what would you recommend I use instead for parsing CSV and grabbing only certain keywords and their data?

Comment: There will be too much discussion for this site. Can you ask the question on github or the google group? https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/csvhelper

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser**

get below code example from above article

```
static void Main()
        {
            string csv_file_path=@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv";

            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

            Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
        {
            DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

            try
            {

            using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
                {
                    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                    }

                    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fieldData[i] == "")
                            {
                                fieldData[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return csvData;
        }
```