# ASP.NET - How to properly split a string for search?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, search, key-value

I'm trying to build a search that is similar to that on Google (with regards to exact match encapsulated in double quotes).

Let's use the following phrase for an example

> "phrase search" single terms [different phrase]

Currently if I use the following code

```
        Dim searchTermsArray As String() = searchTerms.Split(New String() {" ", ",", ";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        For Each entry In searchTermsArray
            Response.Write(entry & "<br>")
        Next
```

my output is

> "phrase
>   search"
>   single
>   terms
>   [different
>   phrase]

but what I really need is to build a key value pair

```
phrase search     |  table1  
single            |  table1  
terms             |  table1  
different phrase  |  table2
```

where table1 is a table with general info, and table2 is a table of "tags" similar to that on stackoverflow.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to properly capture the input?

Comment: The urge to make a snarky comment about "similar to google" is so strong.

Comment: I'm just using that as a reference point.  I'd like to be able to search multiple words enclosed in double quotes as opposed to breaking them apart into individual words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do is not that trivial. Implementing a search "similar to Google's" is far beyond parsing the search string.

I'd suggest you not to reinvent the wheel and instead use production ready solutions such as [Apache Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Those cope with both parsing and fulltext search.

But if you only need to parse this kind of strings then you should really consider solution Pete pointed to.

Comment: definitely recommend lucene.net if you really want search-ability akin to "googling"

Comment: search is a very minor part of my application.  Basically the site is an events listing site, and I need to be able to search for key words (like band or venue names - including names with spaces), but also filter by tags if they use square braces.

Comment: alright... after researching Lucene.NET, it looks like the right solution for me.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how fancy you plan in getting, you might consider the search grammar/implementation that's included with Irony.

http://irony.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Search string parsing is a non-regular problem.  That means that while a regular expression can get deceptively close, it won't take you all the way there without using proprietary extensions, building an unmaintainable mess of an expression, leaving nasty edge cases open that don't work how you'd like, or some combination of the three.

Instead, there are three correct ways to handle this:

1. Use a third-party solution like Lucene.
2. Build a grammar via something like antlr.
3. Build your own state machine.

For a problem of this level (and assuming that search is core enough to what you're doing to really want to implement it yourself), I'd probably go with option 3.  This makes more sense when you realize that regular expressions are themselves instructions for how to set up state machines.  All you're doing is building that right into your code.  This should give you the ability to tune performance and features as well, without requiring adding a larger lexer component into your code.

For an example of how you might do this take a look at my answer to this question:
[Reading CSV files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544721/reading-csv-files-in-c/1544743#1544743)
hat I would do is build a state machine to parse the string character by character.  This will be the easiest way to implement a fully-correct solution, and should also result in the fastest code.