# Regular expression to remove whitespace around a comma, except when quoted

Tags: c#, .net, regex, csv, replace

I have a CSV file that has rows resembling this:

```
1,  4,     2, "PUBLIC, JOHN Q" ,ACTIVE , 1332
```

I am looking for a regular expression replacement that will match against these rows and spit out something resembling this:

```
1,4,2,"PUBLIC, JOHN Q",ACTIVE,1332
```

I thought this would be rather easy:  I made the expression `([ \t]+,)` and replaced it with `,`.  I made a complement expression `(,[ \t]+)` with a replacement of `,` and I thought I had achieved a good means of right-trimming and left-trimming strings.

...but then I noticed that my `"PUBLIC, JOHN Q"` was now `"PUBLIC,JOHN Q"` which isn't what I wanted.  (Note the space following the comma is now gone).

What would be the appropriate expression to trim the white space before and after a comma, but leave quoted text untouched?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I am using an application to handle the file.  This application allows me to define multiple regular expression replacements; it does not provide a parsing capability.  While this may not be the ideal mechanism for this, it would sure beat making another application for this one file.

Comment: Why don't you parse?

Comment: Use a CSV parser - don't try to reinvent the wheel!  Check out [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

Comment: I would parse the file and build it back together.  No need for RegEx which I don't funny understand.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4829787/2145211) looks good.  You could split it using a CSV parser then join it back up

Comment: I am using a previously built application that allows for regular expression transforms.  Parsing would require a custom built transform that I would rather avoid building at this point.

Comment: You will have a monstrosity of a RegEx, as it'll have to account for detecting whether it is between quotes, and whether those quotes have been escaped or not. As the other commenters say: parse, then rebuild without whitespace.

Comment: Probably wrong tool for the job: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166454/can-the-csv-format-be-defined-by-a-regex

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not really an option for me.  A monstrosity regex is better than creating a new application for this one file.

Comment: This is a .NET / C# question, right? So you are writing C# code... how would a "new application" be necessary for a parser-based solution, while using regex would work?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs If you don't want a programming answer you shouldn't have tagged it with C# and .Net.

Comment: @Ralf I tagged it with C# and .Net because it has a different flavor of regex than perl/ php/ java/ javascript;  I just wanted to clarify.   The application I am using is an internal app written in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the engine used by your tool is the C# regular expression engine, then you can try the following expression:

```
(?<!,\s*"(?:[^\\"]|\\")*)\s+(?!(?:[^\\"]|\\")*"\s*,)
```

replace with empty string.

The guys answers assumed the quotes are balanced and used counting to determine if the space is part of a quoted value or not.

My expression looks for all spaces that are not part of a quoted value.

[RegexHero Demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=97a490bc-6985-4e77-b26a-9761f534bea2)

Comment: Hi @Sniffer what does (?<!, mean? (I am relatively new to regular expression and don't know the meaning of < and ! in a group (the ? stands for non capturing group right?)

Comment: @lucacerone it's been a while since I worked with regular expressions so you need to check C# documentation to be sure, but I remember this is a negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

Going with some CSV library or parsing the file yourself would be much more easier, and IMO should be preferable option here.

But if you really insist on a regex, you can use this one:

```
"\s+(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

And replace it with empty string - `""`

This regex matches one or more whitespaces, followed by an even number of quotes. This will of course work only if you have balanced quote.

```
(?x)       # Ignore Whitespace
\s+        # One or more whitespace characters       
(?=        # Followed by 
   (          # A group - This group captures even number of quotes
     [^\"]*     # Zero or more non-quote characters
     \"         # A quote
     [^\"]*     # Zero or more non-quote characters
     \"         # A quote 
   )*         # Zero or more repetition of previous group
   [^\"]*     # Zero or more non-quote characters
   $          # Till the end
)          # Look-ahead end
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do the job:

```
(?<!(^[^"]*"[^"]*(("[^"]*){2})*))[\t ]*,[ \t]*
```

Which matches `[\t ]*,[ \t]*`, only when not preceded by an odd number of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string format(string val)
        {
            if (val.StartsWith("\"")) val = " " + val;
            string[] vals = val.Split('\"');
            for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i += 2) vals[i] = vals[i].Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", "");
            return string.Join("\t", vals);
        }
```

This will work if you have properly closed quoted strings in between

Answer (score 0):

Forget the regex (See Bart's comment on the question, regular expressions aren't suitable for CSV).

```
public static string ReduceSpaces( string input )
{
    char[] a = input.ToCharArray();
    int placeComma = 0, placeOther = 0;
    bool inQuotes = false;
    bool followedComma = true;
    foreach( char c in a ) {
        inQuotes ^= (c == '\"');
        if (c == ' ') {
            if (!followedComma)
                a[placeOther++] = c;
        }
        else if (c == ',') {
            a[placeComma++] = c;
            placeOther = placeComma;
            followedComma = true;
        }
        else {
            a[placeOther++] = c;
            placeComma = placeOther;
            followedComma = false;
        }
    }
    return new String(a, 0, placeComma);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/NEKm09