# how to read a CSV file to a List<myClass>?

Tags: c#

is it possible to create a List of my own class from a CSV file?

the file e.g. looks like:

```
ID;NAME
1;Foo
2;Bar
```

then I have a class like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

is it possible to generate a list of this class out of the cvs file? maybe with some library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541503/parsing-a-csv-file-with-c-ignoring-thousand-separators/5541553#5541553

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CSV parser such as [`FileHelpers`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) or [FastCSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). If you don't want to use third party libraries you may take a look at the built-in [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class which could be used like that:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> Parse(string path)
{
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        parser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
        parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        // Skip over header line.
        parser.ReadLine();

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            yield return new MyClass()
            {
                id = fields[0],
                name = fields[1]
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
List<MyClass> list = Parse("data.csv").ToList();
```

But **never**, please **[`never roll your own CSV parser`](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)** as other people suggested you here as answers to your question.

Comment: never say never. if you know your file structure, maybe writing something small isn't the baddest thing.

Comment: You know the file structure. It's CSV :-) `maybe writing something small isn't the baddest thing.`. Quote from here (http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp): `It's now eight weeks since you said "I know! I'll just use String.Split(..."`.

Comment: lol okay :) i'm a fan of FileHelpers too. however before FileHelpers was here i splitted and parsed on my own and that stuff still running ;-)