# How to ignore a character while Splitting a string in C#

Tags: c#

I've a string like this

```
 1,2,3,"a,b,c",4,"5,6"
```

I want split above string using `.Split(',');`

**Expected**:

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. a,b,c
5. 4
6. 5,6

**Actual**: As usual, it is splitting 4 and 6 also. It is default behaviour. But  any other ways where can i get ehat i am expecting?

Comment: What you have is a CSV. Use a CSV parser.

Comment: Any example or reference please

Comment: CSV parsers are extremely common. A simple google search of the terms `C# CSV` will yield a huge amount of results.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854550/csv-parser-to-parse-double-quotes-via-oledb, Method: ParseRowToList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var result = Regex.Split(myString, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)\");
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2C(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*%5C%22%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*%5C%22)*%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*%24)&i=%201%2C2%2C3%2C%22a%2Cb%2Cc%22%2C4%2C%225%2C6%22)**

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your Solution, save more time of mine :)