# Most efficient way to process a large csv in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, search, csv

Forgive my noobiness but I just need some guidance and I can't find another question that answers this.  I have a fairly large csv file (~300k rows) and I need to determine for a given input, whether any line in the csv begins with that input.  I have sorted the csv alphabetically, but I don't know:

1) how to process the rows in the csv- should I read it in as a list/collection, or use OLEDB, or an embedded database or something else?

2) how to find something efficiently from an alphabetical list (using the fact that it's sorted to speed things up, rather than searching the whole list)

Comment: Do you need to re-load the file every time, or can you cache it in memory, such as in a dictionary or hash table?

Comment: You could try [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/), if you don't want to write a CSV parser.  Please tell us if this is a specific point-solution, or if you need a generalized reader.  As it is, your question is a bit... under-specified.

Comment: @Steven Doggart As long as it's loaded at some point- the data isn't changing.

Comment: Yeah, I would look at FileHelpers or Sebastian Lorien's [Fast CSV Reader.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader).  This is one of those problems that's been well-solved by others.

Comment: `FileHelpers`?  Why not just use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class that's part of the .NET framework?

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Doing CSV properly is harder than most people think it is.  But thanks for the link; I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I don't need a generalized reader, just for this application.  The user will input some text and I want to find the line (if any) in the csv that starts with that text.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Using `TextFieldParser` wouldn't mean implementing your own CSV parser. I haven't used it, but from the documentation it looks like a generalized version of a CSV parser.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, `TextFieldParser` properly handles CSV, including multi-line cells, escaping, etc.

Comment: What is process rows?  Do you need to split out the columns or are you just dealing with a line at a time?

Comment: @Blam I just need to find that row and I can grab the other values from the row since they'll always be in the same position (e.g. after the second comma)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't give enough specifics to give you a concrete answer but...

---

IF the CSV file changes often then use OLEDB and just change the SQL query based on your input.

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "] WHERE Column1 LIKE 'blah%'";
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
          @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileDirectoryPath + 
          ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + hasHeaderRow + "\""))
```

---

IF the CSV file doesn't change often and you run a lot of "queries" against it, load it once into memory and quickly search it each time.

IF you want your search to be an exact match on a column use a Dictionary where the key is the column you want to match on and the value is the row data.

```
Dictionary<long, string> Rows = new Dictionar<long, string>();
...
if(Rows.ContainsKey(search)) ...
```

IF you want your search to be a partial match like StartsWith then have 1 array containing your searchable data (ie: first column) and another list or array containing your row data. Then use C#'s built in binary search http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx

```
string[] SortedSearchables = new string[];
List<string> SortedRows = new List<string>();
...
string result = null;
int foundIdx = Array.BinarySearch<string>(SortedSearchables, searchTerm);
if(foundIdx < 0) {
    foundIdx = ~foundIdx;
    if(foundIdx < SortedRows.Count && SortedSearchables[foundIdx].StartsWith(searchTerm)) {
        result = SortedRows[foundIdx];
    }
} else {
    result = SortedRows[foundIdx];
}
```

**NOTE** code was written inside the browser window and may contain syntax errors as it wasn't tested.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippets, this is really helpful!  I'll try the different methods and see what's fastest.

Answer (score 5):

If you can cache the data in memory, and you only need to search the list on one primary key column, I would recommend storing the data in memory as a `Dictionary` object.  The `Dictionary` class stores the data as key/value pairs in a hash table.  You could use the primary key column as the key in the dictionary, and then use the rest of the columns as the value in the dictionary.  Looking up items by key in a hash table is typically very fast.

For instance, you could load the data into a dictionary, like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> data = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("C:\test.csv"))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            data[fields[0]] = fields;
        }
        catch (MalformedLineException ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could get the data for any item, like this:

```
string fields[] = data["key I'm looking for"];
```

Comment: That will work, if you have the exact key you're looking for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Correct.  I was just basing my answer on the requirements given in the original question: *"I need to determine for a given input, whether any line in the csv begins with that input"*.  If that's all that needs to be done, it seems to me that a dictionary is a great solution.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any experience with dictionary objects but I'll look into this.

Comment: My understanding of that requirement is different.  It could be the input spans columns or it could be the input is only part of a column.

Comment: @ebyrob That's true.  I'm assuming that by "begins with", a specific number of columns was meant, most likely just the first column.

Comment: @Steven Doggart correct.  I'm looking for a value in the first column, and if it's found then retrieve values from the other columns.

Comment: Given the requirement of "exactly one column match" this is probably the simplest/best solution.  (Only question might be if it was necessary to use up less memory than the full file size, or full key size, all the time)

Answer (score 5):

If you're only doing it once per program run, this seems pretty fast.  (Updated to use StreamReader instead of FileStream based on comments below)

```
    static string FindRecordBinary(string search, string fileName)
    {
        using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            long min = 0; // TODO: What about header row?
            long max = fs.BaseStream.Length;
            while (min <= max)
            {
                long mid = (min + max) / 2;
                fs.BaseStream.Position = mid;

                fs.DiscardBufferedData();
                if (mid != 0) fs.ReadLine();
                string line = fs.ReadLine();
                if (line == null) { min = mid+1; continue; }

                int compareResult;
                if (line.Length > search.Length)
                    compareResult = String.Compare(
                        line, 0, search, 0, search.Length, false );
                else
                    compareResult = String.Compare(line, search);

                if (0 == compareResult) return line;
                else if (compareResult > 0) max = mid-1;
                else min = mid+1;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This runs in 0.007 seconds for a 600,000 record test file that's 50 megs.  In comparison a file-scan averages over half a second depending where the record is located.  (a 100 fold difference)

Obviously if you do it more than once, caching is going to speed things up.  One simple way to do partial caching would be to keep the StreamReader open and re-use it, just reset min and max each time through.  This would save you storing 50 megs in memory all the time.

**EDIT:** Added knaki02's suggested fix.

Comment: So why don't you use a System.IO.StreamReader?!

Comment: @Adriano I'm pretty sure StreamReader doesn't seek properly due to buffering.  Based on some googling it didn't seem worth trying.

Comment: you "wrap" the FileStream into a StreamReader and you access underlying stream via StreamReader only. Of course it works (and it manages encoding via BOM too).

Comment: @Adriano Looks like you're right.  But only If I call `StreamReader.DiscardBufferedData()` every loop.  Note: FileStream is wrapped by default if you pass a file name to StreamReader.  BaseStream.Position and Length are needed for the seeking.

Comment: I don't get why you have to discard the buffer, you loop lines with ReadLine() and you stop with the one you're looking for (why seeking?)

Comment: @Adriano It's a binary search through the file without loading the whole thing into memory.  It's at least 100 times faster than calling `File.ReadAllLines()` and uses much less memory.

Comment: @knaki02 doh!  You're right.  This code definitely isn't production ready.  If you've got a fix that doesn't increase the line (or semicolon) count by all means edit it!  (I'm thinking an `if(mid==0)` around first `fs.ReadLine()` might help but I'd have to test it...)

Comment: it fails without changing `while (min + 1 < max)` into `while (min + 1 <= max)`

Comment: @knaki02 You're saying `while( min < max )` ?  Feel free to change as you like.  If you're feeling finished but not sure I'll test it some.

Comment: @ebyrob Ok, I've changed the convergence in your code, since I couldn't make it pass my units test differently...

Comment: @knaki02 I don't see another edit, just the first one.  Note: You can add these lines at top (inelegant but effective) `string line = fs.ReadLine(); if (line.StartsWith(search)) return line;`  Slightly faster might be after the loop `if(min == 0) // check first line`.

Comment: @knaki02 Your fix looked logical, I attempted to salvage it from the moderation system.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3):

Given the CSV is sorted - if you can load the entire thing into memory (If the only processing you need to do is a .StartsWith() on each line) - you can use a [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to have exceptionally fast searching.

Maybe something like this (NOT TESTED!):

```
var csv = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\file.csv").ToList();
var exists = csv.BinarySearch("StringToFind", new StartsWithComparer());
```

...

```
public class StartsWithComparer: IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if(x.StartsWith(y))
            return 0;
        else
            return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't have to load it into memory to do a binary search of the file: http://blog.sarah-happy.ca/2010/04/binary-search-of-sorted-text-file.html  However, for files a btree search would be even faster, but that's probably going to be more work than it's worth.  (requires knowledge of disk geometry)

Comment: This would involve loading the whole thing into a list, right?  I'm not sure how else to do binary search in .NET besides the List<T>.BinarySearch Method

Comment: You'd have to stream past (at best) 50% of the lines in the open file if you didn't read it into memory - this sounds like it'd be far slower (but obv. use far less memory)

Comment: @ebyrob thanks, I'll try to figure out how to convert that into C#, I don't know java

Comment: @DaveBish Does `System.IO.FileStream.Seek()` read the entire file contents or can it skip around to buffered sections of the file?

Comment: @DaveBish yeah, but you can always go backwards (or start early enough that you scan forward for 2 to get one full line) from my earlier link:  `file.seek(mid); file.readLine(); line = file.readLine();` bright girl that Sarah.

Comment: This assumes lines are distributed across the file, in a correlation to the byte-size (The middle of the file in bytes is close to the middle of the file in lines). quite a big assumption, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this quickly for work, could be improved on...

Define the column numbers:

```
private enum CsvCols
{
    PupilReference = 0,
    PupilName = 1,
    PupilSurname = 2,
    PupilHouse = 3,
    PupilYear = 4,
}
```

Define the Model

```
public class ImportModel
{
    public string PupilReference { get; set; }
    public string PupilName { get; set; }
    public string PupilSurname { get; set; }
    public string PupilHouse { get; set; }
    public string PupilYear { get; set; }
}
```

Import and populate a list of models:

```
  var rows = File.ReadLines(csvfilePath).Select(p => p.Split(',')).Skip(1).ToArray();

    var pupils = rows.Select(x => new ImportModel
    {
        PupilReference = x[(int) CsvCols.PupilReference],
        PupilName = x[(int) CsvCols.PupilName],
        PupilSurname = x[(int) CsvCols.PupilSurname],
        PupilHouse = x[(int) CsvCols.PupilHouse],
        PupilYear = x[(int) CsvCols.PupilYear],

    }).ToList();
```

Returns you a list of strongly typed objects

Comment: Any way the Split could be improved to handle quoted values?

Answer (score 1):

**If your file is in memory** (for example because you did sorting) and you keep it as an array of strings (lines) then you can use a simple **bisection search** method. You can start with the code on this question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/generic-binary-search), just change the comparer to work with `string` instead of `int` and to check only the beginning of each line.

If you have to re-read the file each time because it may be changed or it's saved/sorted by another program then the most simple algorithm is the best one:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenText(path))
{
    // Replace this with you comparison, CSV splitting
    if (stream.ReadLine().StartsWith("..."))
    {
        // The file contains the line with required input
    }
}
```

Of course you may **read the entire file in memory** (to use LINQ or `List<T>.BinarySearch()`) each time but this is **far from optimal** (you'll read everything even if you may need to examine just few lines) and the file itself could even be too large.

If you **really** need something more and you do not have your file in memory because of sorting (but you should **profile** your actual performance compared to your requirements) you have to implement a better search algorithm, for example the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/fast-text-search-with-boyer-moore).

Comment: Thanks, I already have the file sorted so it would be an extra step to load it into memory.  I'll take a look at the CodeReview link.

Answer (score 1):

OP stated really just needs to search based on line.

The questions is then to hold the lines in memory or not.

If the line 1 k then 300 mb of memory.
If a line is 1 meg then 300 gb of memory.

Stream.Readline will have a low memory profile
Since it is sorted you can stop looking once it is greater than.

If you hold it in memory then a simple

```
List<String>
```

With LINQ will work.
LINQ is not smart enough to take advantage of the sort but against 300K would still be pretty fast.

BinarySearch will take advantage of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try the free [CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). No Need to invent the wheel over and over again ;)

1) If you do not need to store the results, just iterate though the CSV - handle each line and forget it. If you need to process all lines again and again, store them in a List or Dictionary (with a good key of course)

2) Try the generic extension methods like this

```
var list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
string oneA = list.FirstOrDefault(entry => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry) && entry.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWidth("a"));
IEnumerable<string> allAs = list.Where(entry => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry) && entry.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWidth("a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my VB.net Code.  It is for a Quote Qualified CSV, so for a regular CSV, change `Let n = P.Split(New Char() {""","""})` to `Let n = P.Split(New Char() {","})`

```
Dim path as String = "C:\linqpad\Patient.txt"
Dim pat = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
Dim Patz = From P in pat _
    Let n = P.Split(New Char() {""","""}) _
    Order by n(5) _
    Select New With {
        .Doc =n(1), _
        .Loc = n(3), _
        .Chart = n(5), _
        .PatientID= n(31), _
        .Title = n(13), _
        .FirstName = n(9), _
        .MiddleName = n(11), _
        .LastName = n(7), 
        .StatusID = n(41) _
        }
Patz.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would recommend finding a dedicated CSV parser (like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544743/3043)). However, I noticed this line in your question:

> I need to determine for a given input, whether any line in the csv begins with that input.

That tells me that computer time spend parsing CSV data before this is determined is time wasted. You just need code to simply match text for text, and you can do that via a string comparison as easily as anything else.

Additionally, you mention that the data is sorted. This should allow you speed things up *tremendously*... but you need to be aware that to take advantage of this you will need to write your own code to make seek calls on low-level file streams. This will be *by far* your best performing result, but it will also *by far* require the most initial work and maintenance.

I recommend an engineering based approach, where you set a performance goal, build something relatively simple, and measure the results against that goal. In particular, start with the 2nd link I posted above. The CSV reader there will only load one record into memory at a time, so it should perform reasonably well, and it's easy to get started with. Build something that uses that reader, and measure the results. *If they meet your goal, then stop there.*

If they don't meet your goal, adapt the code from the link so that as you read each line you first do a string comparison (before bothering to parse the csv data), and only do the work to parse csv for the lines that match. This should perform better, but only do the work if the first option does not meet your goals. When this is ready, measure the performance again.

Finally, if you still don't meet the performance goal, we're into the territory of writing low-level code to do a binary search on your file stream using seek calls. This is likely the best you'll be able to do, performance-wise, but it will be very messy and bug-prone code to write, and so you only want to go here if you absolutely do not meet your goals from earlier steps.

Remember, performance is a feature, and just like any other feature you need to evaluate how you build for that feature relative to real design goals. "As fast as possible" is not a reasonable design goal. Something like "respond to a user search within .25 seconds" is a real design goal, and if the simpler but slower code still meets that goal, you need to stop there.