# CSV-file values to List<List>

Tags: c#, list, csv

I have a CSV file that I want some values from. One problem is that I don't know how many columns the file has. The number can be different every time I get a new CSV file. It will always have columns and rows with values. I will get it from a normal excel-file.

I want the method to return a `List<List>`.

**ListA**(FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber... and so on) here I don't know how many items ListA will have. It can be different every time.

Inside ListA I want lists of persons like this:

**ListA**[FirstName] = **List1**(Zlatan, Lionel, Anders.....)

**ListA**[LastName] = **List2**(Ibrahimovic, Messi, Svensson.....) .. and so on.

Comment: there are many ways to accomplish this.. you need to do more research on your end look into how to create a class, also look at how to use the Split() method.. look at how to use Generics in regards to `List<T>` please show more effort ..nobody will give you the answer nor help without you showing at least what you have tried..

Comment: Made the question clearer, fixed grammar.

Comment: I am so sorry for the bad post. I'm happy for all help you guys get me. I got a solution from my friend and posted that. Should I update the question anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution and it's working for me.  My friend made it so all creed to him. No user here on stackoverflow so I post it instead.

```
    private List<Attributes> LoadCsv()
    {
        string filename = @"C:\Desktop\demo.csv";
        // Get the file's text.
        string whole_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);

        // Split into lines.
        whole_file = whole_file.Replace('\n', '\r');
        string[] lines = whole_file.Split(new char[] { '\r' },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // See how many rows and columns there are.
        int num_rows = lines.Length;
        int num_cols = lines[0].Split(';').Length;

        // Allocate the data array.
        string[,] values = new string[num_rows, num_cols];

        // Load the array.
        for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)
        {
            string[] line_r = lines[r].Split(';');
            for (int c = 0; c < num_cols; c++)
            {
                values[r, c] = line_r[c];
            }
        }

        var attr = new List<Attributes>();
        for (var r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)
        {
            if (r == 0)
            {
                for (var c = 0; c < num_cols; c++)
                {
                    attr.Add(new Attributes());
                    attr[c].Name = values[r, c];

                    attr[c].Value = new List<String>();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (var b = 0; b < num_cols; b++)
                {
                    var input = values[r, b];
                    attr[b].Value.Add(input);
                }
            }
        }
        // Return the values.
        return attr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class Person

```
class person {
    private string FirstName;
    private string LastName;
    // others
}
```

[Open the File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and split each row in the file with the [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Method then convert each value and create Objects, which you can add to a List.

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(personFromFile);
```

Thats a pretty short solution but it works

**Edit: Variable Fields per Row**

If thats the case you could use a `List<string[]> stringArraylist;` and then add the results of the `String.Split()`-Method to it.

```
List<string[]> stringArraylist;
stringArraylist = new List<string[]>();
stringArraylist.Add("Andrew;Pearson;...;lololo;".Split(';'));
```

Is that more of what you wanted?

Comment: I Think the hole point of the OP is that he **doesn't** know how many columns he will get, hence your solution is not appropriate to his problem.

Comment: i am with you on this.  It probably doesn't matter how many columns the .csv has?  He should parse the .csv into his object and ignore the extra or missing columns.

Comment: so then he could simply put the Arrays returned from the `String.Split()`-Method in side a `List<string[]> stringArraylist;`  - *look up the edit*

Comment: @JasonWilliams U right, or he does it like in the edit. Depends on the usecase.

Comment: I'd use a List<Dictionary<string, string>> to make lookups easier and to avoid issues dealing with array length.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions on SO that deal with parsing CSV files. See here for one: [Reading CSV files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544721/reading-csv-files-in-c-sharp/1544743#1544743). I am fairly certain there are some solutions built in to .NET, though I can't recall what they are at the moment. (@ZoharPeled suggested [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx))

Most of the parsing solutions with give you a collection of rows where each item is a collection of columns. So assuming you have something like a `IEnumerable<IList<string>>`, you could create a class and use LINQ queries to get what you need:

```
public class CSVColumns 
{
    public IEnumerable<IList<string>> CSVContents { get; private set; }

    public CSVColumns(IEnumerable<IList<string>> csvcontents)
    {
        this.CSVContents = csvcontents;
    }

    public List<string> FirstNames
    {
        get { return GetColumn("FirstName"); }
    }

    public List<string> LastNames
    {
        get { return GetColumn("LastName"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a collection of the column data based on the name of the column
    /// from the header row.
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> GetColumn(string columnname) 
    {
        //Get the index of the column with the name
        var firstrow = CSVContents.ElementAtOrDefault(0);

        if (firstrow != null)
        {
            int index = -1;
            foreach (string s in firstrow)
            {
                index++;
                if (s == columnname)
                {
                    return GetColumn(index, true);
                }
            }
        }

        return new List<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all items from a specific column number but skips the
    /// header row if needed.
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> GetColumn(int index, bool hasHeaderRow = true) 
    {
        IEnumerable<IList<string>> columns = CSVContents;

        if (hasHeaderRow)
            columns = CSVContents.Skip(1);

        return columns.Select(list =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return list[index];
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        ).ToList();
    }
}
```