# Issue with reading Delimited text file using Miscrosoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 in C#

Tags: c#, import, oledbconnection

Something related to this question might have been asked but not the issue I am facing.My connectionstring looks like this

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="F:\TSData\Case 5262";
Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited';
```

I have a delimited text file with `2 lines` of data and `no header` row but the first row is not read at all. If I have header row then both the lines are read.

**Can anyone suggest a way to read all the rows from a file with no header row.**

Comment: How are you selecting your data? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570128/why-isnt-the-ado-extended-properties-hdr-no-flag-being-obeyed-here is possibly related.

Comment: It is related thanks, but data is read differently. I am using OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand which fails at connection.Open() if I specify entire path in connectionString.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I encounter this problem if I follow the solution  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1458068/2459982

Answer (score 0):

try specifying your Delimiter instead of ',' in connection string and check

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="F:\TSData\Case 5262";
Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited(,)';
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/